# Remove Item that has been randomly picked

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the item that has been randomly picked from namepicker. So one item don't appear twice.

```
const Names = [
{
    name: 'Name1',
    id: 1

},
{
    name: 'Name2',
    id: 2

},
]

btnClick = () => {
  let namePicker = Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]
   Names.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length), 1);
}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The random number has to be computed once, or you could obtain different indexes.

```js
const Names = [{
    name: 'Name1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Name2',
    id: 2
  },
];

let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length);
let namePicker = Names[rnd];
Names.splice(rnd, 1);

console.log('picked ', namePicker);
console.log('Array  ', Names)
```